# How to replace this form: (word.Word) into (word.\nWord) with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a Python code that checks if a string contains something similar to:

- `'word.Word'` => it replaces it with `'word.\nWord'`.
- smallLetter.capitalLetter => smallLeter.\nCapitalLetter.

I found that I should use Python regex (which actually I don't know how to write the format inside it!)

I tried creating this sample:

```
import re
text = 'What is the.What is thef.How did youDo that?F'
text = re.sub(r"(\.+[A-Z])", r".\n;", text)
```

**Input**: `'What are you.How did you.When did youDo that?F'`

**Output**: `'What are you.\now did you.\nhen did youDo that?F'`

I think it worked but I don't want the capital letter to be replaced, I want to keep it in the text.

For example: **Input**: `'Hey.Wow'` -> **Output**: `'Hey.\nWow'`

Comment: Wouldn't a `text.replace('.', '.\n')` work?

Comment: @Tomerikoo, no it would replace the periods in strings like `Mr. Smith` as well.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I didn't expect to get an answer very fast like that. You are amazing! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This RE should be good for matching

```py
expr = r"[a-z]\.[A-Z]"
```

It matches ANY lowercase letter, **followed by** a dot `.` **and** an uppercase letter

You can use the https://regex101.com/ site to check your regexes.

[image]

To replace properly across the text, you should use groups:

```py
re_expr = r"([a-z])\.([A-Z])"
teststring = "What is the.What is thef.How did youDo that?F"

re.sub(re_expr, "\\1.\n\\2", teststring)
```

The updated RE matches the lowercase letter before the `.` and the uppercase letter after `.`, and marks them as GROUPS.
The group definition `"\\1"` is later used to insert them at their places in the substituted string.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of ***matching*** the capital letter, just ***check that it's there*** with a [positive-lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (and same goes for the lower-case letter with a positive-lookbehind):

```
\.+[A-Z]  -->  (?<=[a-z])\.(?=[A-Z])
```

Example:

```py
import re

text = 'What is the.What is thef.how did you.Do that?F'
text = re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])\.(?=[A-Z])", r".\n", text)
print(text)
```

Will give:

```
What is the.
What is thef.how did you.
Do that?F
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/goDse4/3)

Comment: This is a nice way, but it won't check if the letter before  `.` is a letter and is lowercase

Comment: @Icebreaker454 True, I was just building on the OP's code. A bit confusing...